# Creating list of list using Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Having a data frame as below:need to convert to list of list as below:

| product1 | product2 | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Apple | 0 |
| Apple | Mango | 20 |
| Apple | Orange | 24 |
| Mango | Apple | 30 |
| Mango | Mango | 0 |
| Mango | Orange | 24 |
| orange | Apple | 12 |
| orange | orange | 0 |
| orange | mango | 24 |

Need to create a matrix whose logic is like this:

[image: img]

The output needs to be a list of list of format as below:

```
[[0,24,20],[12,0,24],[30,24,0]]
```

I tried the below code:

df.groupby(['product1','product2'])['time'].apply(list)

Comment: OK, and what have you tried?  This is not terrible complicated.

Comment: Can you send this data ? I can give a better answer with it... Though it's not that hard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of this, this is known as a pivot table. You can create it by using [pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) method.

To create the above matrix, you need to write this code.

```
pt = data.pivot_table(index="product1", columns="product2", values="time")
```

To get this in list of list form. Store this in a variable and use this.

```
pt.values.tolist()
```

Comment: I need it in as list of list

Comment: I have updated the answer, sorry for trouble